# Transfer values when date = date, create new column

Tags: r, dataframe, date, math

I have two data frames. Both have a date column. DF A has about 14000 rows and contains daily returns. DF B has about 600 rows and contains the average daily CPI in the respective month. So in DF B only %m-%Y of the date column are decisive. Here is a short example how the data frames look like:

[image]

I would like to compute both DFs with each other. To do so, I want to create a new column in DF A, in which the corresponding value from DF B is entered for all days in month XY. The new Output should look like this:

[image]

I assume that this is feasible by referring to the month and year of the Date columns. However, I am new to R and do not know how to implement this.

Here is my code so far.

```
###################################
#DF A 
library(quantmod)
data.N225 <- getSymbols("^N225",from="1965-01-01", to="2022-02-30", auto.assign=FALSE, src='yahoo') # funktion getSymbols wenn wir Kapitalmarkt haben wollten 
class(data.N225)
data.N225[c(1:3, nrow(data.N225)),]
#View(data.N225)
data.N225<- na.omit(data.N225)
N225 <- data.N225[,6]

N225$Returns<- diff(log(N225$N225.Adjusted))+1
N225[c(1:3,nrow(N225)),]
options(digits=5)
N225.stetig <- N225[-1,2]
N225.stetig[c(1:3,nrow(N225.stetig)),]

DF_A <- as_tibble(data.frame(Date = index(N225.stetig), coredata(N225.stetig)))
View(DF_A)

#################
#DF B
library(mosaic)
library(dplyr)
library(xts)
setwd("/Users/lauraneises/Documents/Masterarbeit/Excel/Japan")
CPI<- read.csv("InflationJapan.csv")
#View(CPI)

CPI$percent <- CPI[,2]/100
CPI$CPI.umsk <- (CPI[,3]/250)
CPI$CPI <- CPI[,4]+1
class(CPI$DATE)
CPI$DATE <- as.Date.character(CPI$DATE, tryFormats =  c("%Y-%m-%d"))
class(CPI$DATE)

DF<- as_tibble(data.frame(Date = index(CPI$DATE), coredata(CPI)))
DF_B <- DF[,c(2,6)]
options(digits=7)
View(DF_B)

##### EDIT 
dfa <- DF_A %>%
  mutate(
    date = str_c(str_sub(date, 1, 6), "19", str_sub(date, 7, 8)),
    date = dmy(date),
    month = floor_date(date, "month"))

dfb <- DF_B %>%
  mutate(
    date = str_c(str_sub(date, 1, 6), "19", str_sub(date, 7, 8)),
    date = dmy(date))

dfa %>% 
  left_join(dfb2, by = c("month" = "date"))
```

The CSV file can be downloaded from the following link.
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1GUlce4wR_lWiCbJivwDadgDYaz2ir0_L?usp=sharing

I hope someone can help me. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Please don't upload code, results or data as images for [these reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).

Answer (score 1):

I've made up a little example to show how it could be done.

It's better if you can provide a small reproducible example like this that we can paste, run and adapt for you.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'lubridate'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     date, intersect, setdiff, union

dfa <- tribble(
  ~date, ~return,
  "06-01-65", 1000,
  "07-01-65", 2000,
  "01-02-65", 3000,
  "02-02-65", 4000,
)

dfb <- tribble(
  ~date, ~cpi,
  "01-01-65", 1,
  "01-02-65", 2
)

dfa2 <- dfa |> 
  mutate(
    date = str_c(str_sub(date, 1, 6), "19", str_sub(date, 7, 8)),
    date = dmy(date),
    month = floor_date(date, "month"))

dfb2 <- dfb |> 
  mutate(
    date = str_c(str_sub(date, 1, 6), "19", str_sub(date, 7, 8)),
    date = dmy(date))

dfa2 |> 
  left_join(dfb2, by = c("month" = "date"))
#> # A tibble: 4 × 4
#>   date       return month        cpi
#>   <date>      <dbl> <date>     <dbl>
#> 1 1965-01-06   1000 1965-01-01     1
#> 2 1965-01-07   2000 1965-01-01     1
#> 3 1965-02-01   3000 1965-02-01     2
#> 4 1965-02-02   4000 1965-02-01     2
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you! Can you explain to me what you are doing in these line  ***date = str_c(str_sub(date, 1, 6), "19", str_sub(date, 7, 8)),
    date = dmy(date),*** when you use the mutate() function? And what are the numbers 1, 6, "19" 7, 8 for? Do I have to change them when I adapt the code ?

Comment: `dmy()` converts a character string dd-mm-yy to a special date object that makes it easier to manipulate dates.  It does though assume that it's the 21st century, so the `str_sub` bit is to first change 65 to 1965, then use `dmy` to convert to a date. If your dates are 2065, then you don't need to do the `str_sub` bit.

Comment: So "19" is inserted between position 6 and position 7 in the character string before the conversion to a date object. When it's a date object you can do things like find the date floor for the month, i.e. the first day of the month.

Comment: Thank you. I tried to run your example an it gives me the following error: Error in stri_sub(string, from = start, to = end) : 
  argument `str` should be a character vector (or an object coercible to)

Comment: Have you changed anything?

Comment: If you copy your code to the clipboard, then run `reprex::reprex()` then paste the clipboard in stackoverflow, we can see what you're seeing.

Comment: I changes |> to %>% and now your example works! But when I try to adapt it to the large data frames, I get this Erroro again: Error in `h()`:
! Problem with `mutate()` input `date`.
✖ argument `str` should be a character vector (or an object coercible to)
ℹ Input `date` is `str_c(str_sub(date, 1, 6), "19", str_sub(date, 7, 8))`.

Comment: `|>` is essentially the new `%>%` in newer releases of base R. You'll need to create a small reprex like mine but including a sample of the data that is causing your problem. It may be that some of your dates in the large dataset look different to the example.

Comment: Thank you so much for trying to help me. I am trying to create a reprex but it ist not working. Sorry, I am a beginner... I added your solution to my code above. Maybe if you run it you will see the error I get. Thanks so much!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244501/discussion-between-laura-neises-and-carl).